# Communication with server failed: 500 Internal server error and no log files

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat, cloud-foundry

I am trying to understand why I get the following error: `Communication with server failed: 500 Internal server error` from my cloudfoundry application.

What strikes me is that I have no access to log files as one can see from the following screen capture:
[image: No log files...]

Can anyone please help and let me know how to "enable logs" on my cloudfoundry application deployed from STS/eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the CLI tool, VMC? You should be able to inspect the logs using "vmc logs [appname]"

Comment: Thanks Dan. I will give it a try. I was just surprised that no logs showed up in my STS console... Any idea why that is?